# Angular 2 ngIf Syntax error in regular expression on ie9 and ie10

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to make my angular 2 (2.4.1) application fully compatible with ie9 and ie10.
The application works well but there is a little big I haven't been able to solve yet.
When this component (post-viewer) is used:

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts" id="post-container">
    <h1 *ngIf="single">{{post.title}}</h1>
    <h2 *ngIf="!single">{{post.title}}</h2>
    <div id="post-content">
        <div class="post-icons">
            <span class="post-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{post.author}}</span>
            <span class="post-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{post.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</span>
            <span class="post-icon"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i> <gds-cat-resolver [catId]="post?.category" ></gds-cat-resolver> </span>
            <span class="post-icon"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> <gds-tags-resolver [tagsId]="post?.tags"> </gds-tags-resolver> </span>
        </div>
        <p *ngIf="single">{{post.body }}</p>
        <p *ngIf="!single">{{post.body | postMore}} <a [routerLink]="['/post',post.titleUrl]">More...</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div (click)="loadMore()" *ngIf="posts.length > 0 && !single" id="load-more" [class.load-more-disabled]="disable_loadMore">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

by initializing it in the host component in this way (the bug doesn't appear if [single]='true' is omitted):

```
<post-viewer [postPagination]="postPagination" [single]='true'></post-viewer>
```

I receive a strange error on ie9 and ie10: Syntax error in regular expression.

Ie9 console error snapshot: http://postimg.org/image/jjv01f6w3/

Ie10 console error snapshot: http://postimg.org/image/llusgvqkn/

I have been able to isolate the problem in somehow... it's the ngIf directive *ngIf="!single" present in the 12th line causing the problem:

```
<p *ngIf="!single">{{post.body | postMore}} <a [routerLink]="['/post',post.titleUrl]">More...</a></p>
```

If i remove only that ngIf statement the application works fine. It's pretty strange cause there is another identical ngIf statement used in the 3rd line and it doesn't cause any problem.

any suggestion?

Comment: You could try `*ngIf="single == false"` No idea if it actually matters, but you can at least try it :)

Comment: unfortunately it didn't make the trick... I'm out of ideas...